# Reading a file in Objective-C, then displaying its contents in UIAlertView message

Tags: objective-c, file

I am making an app for JailBroken iDevices, but I am stuck on one part...

I have a file in /private/var/mobile called "IPs.txt", which contains:

```
10.0.0.24
10.0.0.42
```

And I am trying to read the file, here is what I am using...

```
NSString *hostsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"/private/var/mobile/IPs" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *hostsContent = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:hostsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
UIAlertView *hostsAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Found hosts:" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", hostsContent] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[hostsAlert show];
[hostsAlert release];
```

(This is all in a function called `rightButtonPressed`, which is executed upon clicking the UINavigationBar right button)

I get the UIAlertView just fine. However, the message just says (null).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you pass an `NSError` pointer for the `error:` parameter instead of `nil`, and find out?

Comment: UIAlertView is depricated use rather UIAlertController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:ofType:]` will give you a path to the resource that you provide with your app. `resource` parameter there is a name of the file in the application bundle directory.

As you refer your resource on the absolute path, you can just use

```
NSString *hostsPath = @"/private/var/mobile/IPs.txt";
```

Comment: Oh my goodness I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks for the quick reply!